# How to create a csv file of data created in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I am new to programming. I was wondering if anyone can help me create a csv file for the data that I created in python.
My data looks like this

```
import numpy as np
print np.__version__



a = 0.75 + (1.25 - 0.75)*np.random.sample(10000)
print a
b = 8 + (12 - 8)*np.random.sample(10000)
print b
c = -12 + 2*np.random.sample(10000)
print c
x0 = (-b - np.sqrt(b**2 - (4*a*c)))/(2*a)
print x0
```

The csv file format I am looking to create is 1 column each for a,b,c and x0 (see example below)

[image]

Your expert assistance will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance :-)

Edit 1>>
Input code:

```
import numpy as np
print np.__version__
import csv




a = 0.75 + (1.25 - 0.75)*np.random.sample(10000)
##print a
b = 8 + (12 - 8)*np.random.sample(10000)
##print b
c = -12 + 2*np.random.sample(10000)
##print c
x0 = (-b - np.sqrt(b**2 - (4*a*c)))/(2*a)
##print x0


with open("file.csv",'w') as f:
    f.write('a,b,c,x0\n')
    for val in a,b,c,x0:
        print val
        f.write(','.join(map(str,[a,b,c,x0]))+ '\n')
```

Output
[image]

I am being able to generate the data using for loop command (see pic below). The csv format is not outputting as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four range of values you need to iterate over. Every iteration should correspond to each new line written.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
print np.__version__
import csv


a_range = 0.75 + (1.25 - 0.75)*np.random.sample(10000)
b_range = 8 + (12 - 8)*np.random.sample(10000)
c_range = -12 + 2*np.random.sample(10000)
x0_range = (-b_range - np.sqrt(b_range**2 - (4*a_range*c_range)))/(2*a_range)


with open("file.csv",'w') as f:
    f.write('a,b,c,x0\n')
    for a,b,c,x0 in zip(a_range, b_range, c_range, x0_range):
        f.write(','.join(map(str,[a,b,c,x0]))+ '\n')
```

Comment: Works exactly as I was expecting!. Appreciate your assistance @chefarov :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("file.csv",'w') as f:
  f.write('a,b,c,x0\n')
  --forloop where you generate a,b,c,x0:
    f.write(','.join(map(str,[a,b,c,x0])) + '\n')
```

Comment: Correct. Also add `f.write('a,b,c,x0\n')` before for loop

Comment: @chefarov indeed, if he wants the headers which it appears he does.  Thanks.

Comment: Apreciate your assistance on this bravosierra99 and @chefarov. Can you kindly give an example of how to write the for loop to generate data?

Comment: @MaroofG Um you might want to spend a little more time googling.  It should take you about 2 minutes to figure out how to write a for loop.

Comment: @bravosierra99: I am not being able to get the data in 4 separate columns as expected. heres my code:                                                              <<<with open("file.csv",'w') as f:
    f.write('a,b,c,x0\n')
    for val in a,b,c,x0:
        print val
        f.write(','.join(map(str,[a,b,c,x0]))+ '\n')>>>>                                                                      I am unable to write the code on here in the proper format. This is all new to me, please bear with me.

Comment: @MaroofG edit your question up top so we can see the code properly.

type
EDIT 1:
I tried the following code and it did not work
  <CODE PASTED HERE>